# Как в Excel сделать неравномерную сетку в точечном графике

Tags: excel

подскажите пожалуйста как сделать неравномерную сетку для точечного графика как показано на рисунке.

на оси х допустим точка 100 а на оси у данной точке соответствует любая точка кроме 100, ибо сетка будет равномерной, или кратко масштаб оси х не соответствует оси у.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что такое "неравномерная"? Расстояние между делениями одинаковое вроде

Comment: @dIm0n я имею в виду что на оси х допустим точка 100 а на оси у данной точке соответствует любая точка кроме 100, ибо сетка будет равномерной, или кратко масштаб оси х не соответствует  оси у.

Comment: >> *на оси у данной точке соответствует любая точка кроме 100* На оси y нет точки 100. Вы повторили  то, что написано в заглавном сообщении. От повторения понятнее не стало.